# What happens when pure chlorophyll A absorbs blue light?

Tags: photosynthesis, light, chloroplasts

When pure chlorophyll A is put in the presence of only blue light, what happens? My guess is that the extra energy is released as heat/kinetic energy, and then the electron has dropped to the lowest energy state above the state that would normally release red light when UV light is shone. Then, it would drop to ground state and release red light as normal. Is this correct? The reasoning behind this is that UV is even higher energy than violet/blue light, so the same phenomenon should happen, except with less kinetic energy added. On a side note, what is the next electron state after the one that sends out red light?

Comment: chlorophyll a or chlorophyll b?

Comment: chlorophyll A. 15char